# How can I use omniauth-oauth with the freelancer API?

Tags: omniauth, freelancer.com-api

I'd like to use Ruby on Rails with the Freelancer API.

[Freelancer API](http://developer.freelancer.com/)

[Freelancer Auth Overview](http://developer.freelancer.com/articles/a/u/t/Authentication_Overview_8af1.html)

I assume I need to build a custom strategy using this document as a reference:

[Omniauth-oauth](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth-oauth)

But, I don't understand how to get started.

Answer (score 1):

I am on the same page I guess. May be the following link would give a start to something.

[Sample Code](http://developer.freelancer.com/articles/s/a/m/Sample_Code_8b2c.html#Download)